# Highlight the null value cells in RadGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, telerik, radgrid

I have a radGridView, the user inserts rows, i want to highlight the cell with null values.  For example to make the back  color of the cell Red.
I have tried the below code, but it did not work...

Inside a button

```
for (int j = 0; j < radGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
{
      if (radGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "")                
          radGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;  
}
```

So how to do it? or if there is a better highlight method that notifies the user for the empty cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fadddd,

I'll keep it clean and to the point:

- 03Usr's answer is talking about a row, you want individual cells
- CyberDude's answer doesn't take into account the many events that Telerik's DGV has to modify appearance and functionality

With that said, your code seems to want to highlight empty values (null does not equal empty):

```
private void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.Value != null && e.CellElement.Value.ToString() == "")
        {                    
            radGridView1.Rows[e.CellElement.RowIndex].Cells[e.CellElement.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            radGridView1.Rows[e.CellElement.RowIndex].Cells[e.CellElement.ColumnIndex].Style.CustomizeFill = true;
        }

    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do it in the `ItemDataBound` event, like this:

```
TableCell myCell = ((GridDataItem)e.Item)["ColumnName"];
...
myCell.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `OnRowDataBound="radGridView1_RowDataBound"` to your gridview. This event gets triggered for every gridview row.

In the code behind you can have the following:

```
public void radGridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // do your highlighting here
        if (e.Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
}
```